# How to keyDown SHIFT + "w" while clicking - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, keydown, keyevent

I'm trying to open a link in a new window using selenium with Chrome driver. I'd like to use keyDown to hold SHIFT and "w" while clicking the webelement. These attempts have not worked:

```
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    Action series = act.keyDown(englishButton, Keys.SHIFT).keyDown(englishButton, "w").click(englishButton).build();

    series.perform();
```

The ".keyDown(englishButton, "w")" portion gives me an error there. And I've also tried using java robot:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
englishButton.click();
```

but after importing Robot, KeyEvent wasn't recognizing VK_SHIFT or VK_W as valid entries.

Comment: could you please edit to include error message?

Answer (score 0):

First, in Google Chrome, to open a link in a new tab you don't need to hold down W, just SHIFT.

Second, `.keyDown(englishButton, "w")` shouldn't compile because it takes an `org.openqa.selenium.Keys` instance (not a `char`). If you want to send characters you should use `Actions.sendKeys(CharSequence...)` (it doesn't release the modifier keys unlike `WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)`):

```
Action series = act.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, "w").click(englishButton).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build()
```

This should first key-down on SHIFT+W, then click your button/link, and then release SHIFT (as W isn't a modifier key you don't need to release it).

And if you don't care about holding down W but just SHIFT then you can try the following:

```
Action series = act.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(englishButton).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build()
```

This should simply key-down SHIFT, click your button/link, and then release SHIFT.

Answer (score 0):

"w" button should be "pressed" using `sendKeys()` method. But as @mfulton26 has mentioned, there is no need to do it if you want to open a new tab in Chrome. Also there is no need to use `englishButton` as a first argument in `keyDown()` or `keyUp()` methods. Please take a look:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);

Action series = act.
        keyDown(Keys.SHIFT). // Press Shift key
        click(englishButton). // Click the link
        keyUp(Keys.SHIFT). // Release Shift key
        build(); // Build the chain of actions

series.perform();
```

Hope this helps.